# Linux file permissions issue, unexpected access to file

Tags: linux, web, file-permissions

I'm relatively new to Linux so please excuse my ignorance.

I have a public web directory where I have been experimenting with the permissions to try to learn about them.
I have set up a simple test.php file and set its permissions as follows:

-rw --- ---

Which I was expecting to mean only the owner can access the file and no other.
But, I can still access this file remotely from the web and the test page shows?
This is on a Red Hat web server. 
NOTE: The owner use is not the web access user.

This worries me as I then think maybe a web user could write to the file some how (is it possible?).

Any pointers would be great. I just want to makesure I understand this as it seems to me to be an important security concept.

Cheers
C

Answer (score 1):

The webserver (Apache2, httpd?) should not be able to read the file, unless it is running as root. Is that the case?

Comment: Thanks Weboide,
If I list the processes running apache gives this...

root      6328  0.0  0.1 119052  4236 ?        Ss   Apr06   1:15 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

root      6696  0.0  0.0 125304  1720 ?        Ss   Apr06   1:28 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6697  0.0  0.0 124532   704 ?        S    Apr06   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

...And 6 other www-data entries.

Is this normal to have some root processes and where can I set what user apache uses for web access to the server.

Thanks very much, C.

Comment: Apache2 has very similar results as apache. The process running for httpd is:    root      9856  0.0  0.0   3944   628 pts/0    S+   09:13   0:00 grep httpd      ...it is ROOT, is this incorrect?

Comment: Apache2 seems to be running as www-data, which is fine but you should not be able to read that specific file unless it is owned by www-data.